# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a MacBook 5, 1 (late 2008 unibody). Poor performance. Is it to be expected on a 11 or so year old laptop?

Tags: drivers, performance, macbook, cpu-load

**Note:** I am more interested in the theory behind any answers. I am interested to know if such perceived poor performance is expected. Can it be due to aged hardware, etc? This is a secondary laptop and not critical that I get it running. I am just curious about the reasons why the following might be.

I recently did a fresh install (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on MacBook 5,1). I was happy with Firefox until I found Netflix could not run on it (Is Firefox not supported?).

Netflix ran on Chrome but the video froze (sound continued). Eventually it would catch up to itself. Once it did that, it was able to run the video alright. However, by doing nothing else I realised the load average was around `2.20 2.20 2.20`. Similar thing happened while using YouTube.

Potentially my actual problem is with Chrome?

**RAM INFO:** RAM usage (4GB available) was fine, using less then 2GB.

The other thing I thought could potentially be a problem is that I am running the open-source nouveau drivers. Should I instead be running the proprietary drivers?

Everything is standard (as it comes with fresh installation), nothing else running in background.

Are there any obvious things to toggle with an installation of Linux on a MacBook? Is the CPU potentially being throttled due to poor heat circulation? Or maybe it has something to do with poor battery performance?

My assumption is that 8GB RAM and an SSD won't have an affect on the load average (is that true?).

Comment: Please can [edit ] your question and share your CPU and GPU / iGPU model and  architecture.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Your question is a bit broad and ambiguous. This is [not a forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums) but a Question & Answer site which works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. First of all, there is no Ubuntu 18.03. The load over 2.00 is too much for a 2-core system to be running fluently, you should check running processes (using (h)top). CPU performance should have almost no relation to the battery, especially when the laptop is AC-powered.

Comment: The specific question: `Is poor CPU performance to be expected on an 11 or so year old laptop (similar range of specs to a MacbBook 5, 1) with Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS?`

All else is context that might guide an answer. On startup htop shows an excess of 2.0 load average. Takes quite a while for it to settle down. So yes, it is not running fluently. Terrible performance. I am seeking technical information on what can and can not be the cause.

Not disagreeing with you that question is too broad... but I struggle to see a way to make it more specific. Potentially it should not be asked at all.